# Can you ionise air via thermionic emission of electrons?

Tags: energy, electrons, radiation, air, ionization-energy

Assuming air is made up only of 78% $N_2$ and 22% $O_2$, what percentage of the $N_2$ and $O_2$ would gain a negative charge if held in a container with a high density of free electrons?

Comment: Electrons from a hot cathode don't have much energy, so they can't split either O2 or N2 molecules in to atoms (ionized or not). Merely having some free electrons around will likely mean some attach and make singly-negative ionized molecules. As an aside, it is actually pretty hard to make a nitrogen plasma, much harder than oxygen, hydrogen, helium, or noble gases.

Comment: I take it you mean that some percentage of the $O_2$ and $N_2$ will gain a negative charge in the presence of excess electrons, even if they aren't split into atoms? If so, do you have any recommendations about how to calculate the percentage of $O_2$ and $N_2$ that gain a negative charge?